# Unable to download files in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

Portal users are unable to download files which is available in vf page and whose file size is greater than 1.5 MB  in chrome and IE. Kindly help me.

In my controller i am using this stmt :

```
attachBody = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(itrAttach.Body);
```

In VF Page :

```
<a download="{!attachItem.attachName}" 
             href="data:{!attachItem.attachContentType};base64,{!attachItem.attachBody}" > 
 {!attachItem.attachName} </a>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to download the files from other browsers?

Comment: hi Nilesh, Yes I can able to download the same files in Mozilla Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try this

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, attachment.id)}"
                 target="_blank">{!attachment.name}</apex:outputLink>
```

or

```
<a href="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!attachment.id}" download="
    {!attachment.name}">{!attachment.name}</a>
```